# Simplify a polynomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$8^2n+\frac{16}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

[image]

one step: $8^2 n+8(n+1)+\dfrac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n}$

I have got $\dfrac{434n^2+9n+1}{6n}$ and it seems to be incorrect.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify+8%5E2n%2B%5Cfrac%7B16%7D%7Bn%7D%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7Bn%28n%2B1%29%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7Bn%28n%2B1%29%282n%2B1%29%7D%7B6%7D

Comment: @Surb still getting wrong feedback,added a picture of the expression to be 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

This simplifies to
$$
\frac{1}{6}\left(435n+\frac{1}{n}+50\right).
$$

Hope this helps

**Fixed for error in original post**

Comment: Thanks but, I forgot n before $8^2$

Comment: @gbox Fixed for error in OP.